# New error in supervisord on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, node.js, supervisord

This error seems to have shown up in the latest set of upgrades on ubuntu

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/supervisord", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('supervisor==3.0a10', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.6.egg/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 364, in main
options = ServerOptions()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.6.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 406, in __init__
existing_directory, default=tempfile.gettempdir())
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 254, in gettempdir
tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 201, in _get_default_tempdir
("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))
 IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/usr/lib/python2.6']
```

I think it's a python thing.

I'm running a supervisord process to keep a node.js webserver running, but am no longer able to run supervisord.

Does anyone know how to fix this or know of a very reliable alternative to keeping my node.js webserver running (apart from the seemingly obvious "don't write stuff that crashes")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

_get_default_tempdir just checks access to the temp dirs by writing and deleting a random file into temp dir.  So you might want to check permissions on your temp dirs: '/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/usr/lib/python2.6'

Comment: thanks Alex, see comment, as it turns out the disk was full.  So the next question is about how to find and clear out large files in Ubuntu via SSH (or maybe there are remote gui file management options)

Comment: this really isn't python :) try find / -size +100M -print

Comment: @AlexKreimer I have checked permission it's on 777 root but still giving such a error.

Comment: did you also check that you have space on the device?

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, the disk was full.