# No usable temporary directory found

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to find a temp directory ,
but when i am trying to get the directory using

```
tempfile.gettempdir()
```

it's giving me error of

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 254, in gettempdir
    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 201, in _get_default_tempdir
    ("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))
IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/home/openerp/openerp-server']
```

The permission on the directory is 777 owned by root.

Comment: I only know of this issue turning up if the disk is full, since the method finds a valid directory by attempting to write a temporary file.  I don't suppose that's your issue?

Comment: @BhajunSingh: I was shocked by your claim that Python would determine which directly to use by actually trying to create a file there.  But it's true: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/tempfile.py#l176 - see `_get_default_tempdir()`.  It seems very strange not to just use `os.access()` to check if a directory can be written to.

Comment: I think @BhajunSingh is right, the disk is probably full.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518297/new-error-in-supervisord-on-ubuntu

Comment: @BrentWashburne I have checked that answer, then after i'll check the disk usage.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

This kind of error occured in two case

1. permission(should be drwxrwxrwt and owened by root)
2. space

To check space(disk usage)just run the command on terminal

```
df -h
```

Will list the disk usage on unix and get the output like

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        28G   15G   12G  58% /
```

If the root(mounted on /) usage is 100%.

You need to clean the tmp directory or restart the machine or make some space on the root.

Answer (score 21):

Problem can also occur if **inode** are full.

You can type `df -i`

```
# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            253841     322 253519    1% /dev
tmpfs           255838     430 255408    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     5120000 5120000      0  100% /
tmpfs           255838       1 255837    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           255838       7 255831    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           255838      16 255822    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           255838       4 255834    1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Upvote this. Because this is definitely another reason causing this problem. I was caching a lot of logs that crossed the inode limit. Type df -I and if something is 100% then you need to clear such files. Logged files and caching of data in different files must be the possible issue.

Comment: Either you will run out of space or you will run out the number of files you can create.

Comment: This was my problem! prevented letsencrypt certbot and postgres from working

Answer (score 14):

This error can occur when the file system has been switched to read-only mode.

Comment: Would be more helpful to say how to resolve the problem, not just what it is.

Comment: And what's the solution...?

Comment: You can check to see if this is the issue with the `mount` command. If your filesystem has `ro` instead of `rw`, you're in read-only mode.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem while running a python script in Docker. The following command fixed it for me:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --quiet --filter "dangling=true")
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, but deleted more than needed to be.

Comment: Looks exactly what `docker image prune` do

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue with my Kubernetes deployment that used a Python image and Gunicorn as the entrypoint. I had mistakenly set the following in the K8s config for the container:

```
securityContext:
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

Setting this to `false`, or removing it (it defaults to `false`), fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

**I got the same issue when there was no space on /.**

**Issue:**

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 201, in _get_default_tempdir("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))
IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']  [FAILED]
```

[root@master hue]# df -h

> Filesystem             Size      Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/mapper/vg_master-lv_root
>
> ```
>              35G   34G     0 100%     /
> ```
>
> tmpfs
>                      7.8G   72K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
>
> /dev/sda1
>                      477M   34M  418M   8% /boot

**When I cleared out some space then it worked fine for me.**

[root@master log]# service hue start

Starting hue:                                              [  OK  ]

[root@master log]#

Answer (score 5):

definately a disk space issue,

on terminal, type `df -h` 
you should see output like below ( notice the 100% on one of the filesystems)

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            992M     0  992M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   21M  179M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.8G  0  100% /
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/997
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1042
```

in this case, you need to make space by deleting files, artifacts folders e.t.c on path root `/`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on the Windows 7x64 machine. It was OK with disk space and permissions.

When I excecuted

```
tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='MyPrefix_')
```

manually in python console the directory `%TEMP%\MyPrefix_xxxx` was successfully created.
But when I did the same from script I received the error `IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in [...]`.

I solved the problem using `dir` parameter:

```
 # '.' is a default value for example
 tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='MyPrefix_', dir=os.environ.get('TEMP', '.'))
```

After that from script it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I got this when my root drive (`/dev/sda1`) was corrupted on my Ubuntu.

Rebooted, got the error `/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors`.

Followed instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck, which was to `fsck -y <dev/xxx reported to have error>` ***twice***. Then `exit` to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue earlier today. I started a query embedded in jupyter before going to lunch, and I returned to jupyter throwing some type of error (can't remember what it was exactly). When I tried restarting jupyter in the terminal, I got the error described in OP's question (no usable temporary directory). The answers above didn't work, so I tried restarting my entire VM, at which point I got the error described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually). After following the instructions in that thread's top answer, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. fyi This should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Thanks- can you elaborate? I thought that if someone consulted this thread for an answer to OP's question, they may be interested in the solution I provided. Since it doesn't really fit into the conversation of any of the other answers, I don't know where I would have commented.

Answer (score 0):

The file system may have encountered an error and switched to read-only mode. This can usually be fixed with a reboot.

In my experience with Ubuntu, on reboot you are usually brought to a screen that says "/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced." with a prompt that says `(initramfs)`. You'll need to run `fsck /dev/sda6` (or swap that path out for wherever you have `/` mounted).