# Error while installing pip: FileNotFounError

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd, pip

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit, I'm new to TensorFlow, so I installed Python 3.7.7 64-bit on my computer, but when I trying to download Tensorflow on my computer, it causes an error. So I Googled it, Tensorflow says 'delete temp folder and restart computer' so I did it. But pip error still remains.
Here is my question:

Does Tensorflow support python 3.8.x? and is it OK to install python 32-bit on my computer?
Why python installer doesn't install pip module on my computer?

and here is my error:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 22711, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 187, in main
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tempfile.py", line 348, in mkdtemp
    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tempfile.py", line 117, in 
_sanitize_params
    dir = gettempdir()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tempfile.py", line 286, in 
gettempdir
     tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tempfile.py", line 218, in 
_get_default_tempdir
        raise FileNotFoundError(_errno.ENOENT,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in 
['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 
'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp', 'c:\\temp', 'c:\\tmp', '\\temp', 
'\\tmp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts']

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts>
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996125/no-usable-temporary-directory-found ?

Comment: Yes, I already deleted a temporary file, but it doesn't work on my computer.